# Stop Grunt Contrib Uglify from removing unused Javascript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

There is a function within my Javascript source file that I need to keep within my distribution for posterity (specifically for a sniffer to sniff out some information). It is not being called, but it needs to stay.

The Grunt task, [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) is removing this method because it is uncalled in my application.

How can I utilize the compression provided by grunt-contrib-uglify, without removing any code that is deemed unusable by this Grunt library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `options: unused` to false

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    options: {
      compress: {
        unused: false
      }
    },
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Source: [UglifyJS global definitions documentation](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress#global-defs)

`unused        : true,  // drop unused variables/functions`